# Karate Multi-url access in a single scenario

Tags: karate

I want to access multiple url in a single scenario.

When the url is defined in `Background` and the another url is used in `Scenario`, the url is changed.

If I use `path`, the behavior is not expected.
Can it fix `url` in `Background`?

```
Feature: examples

Background:
    * url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

Scenario: get all users and then get the first user by id
    Given path 'users'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given url 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories'
        And param q = 'intuit/karate' 
    When method get
    Then status 200

    # The expected behavior is accessed to 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'.
    # But the accual behavior is accessed to 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories/users'.
    Given path 'users'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you move `Given url 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories'` to a second `Scenario:` it will work fine.

This is a deliberate design. Look at the [hello world example](https://gist.github.com/ptrthomas/d5a2d9e15d0b07e4f1b46f692a599f93). It makes 2 calls, but the `url` is mentioned only once, because the second call is just a `path` addition. This is the typical REST pattern.

So if you need to really do a different API call, you have to use the full `url`:

```
Background:
    * def baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'

Scenario: get all users and then get the first user by id
    Given url baseUrl
    And path 'users'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given url 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories'
    And param q = 'intuit/karate' 
    When method get
    Then status 200

    Given url baseUrl
    And path 'users'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
OK, I use `url` keyword at each `Given`.